# NSLog shows NSString correctly - Trying to show the string on a label crashes the app (unrecognized selector)

Tags: iphone, nsstring, console, nsarray, uilabel

App crashes when trying to update an `UILabel` with a `NSString`.
Showing the same `NSString` on `console` works.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.connectionData)
    {
        NSError *error;
        self.dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        self.matchesArray = self.dict[@"matches"];

        NSString *title = [self.matchesArray valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"NSString TITLE contains: %@", title);
        self.titleLabel.text = title;
    }
}
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
2013-01-16 13:54:08.550 ZEITreisen[3168:c07] NSString TITLE contains: (
    "Mark und Dollar"
)
2013-01-16 13:54:08.552 ZEITreisen[3168:c07] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde93850
(lldb)
```

Comment: On which line is it crashing?

Comment: self.titleLabel.text = title;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title` is not `NSString`, it is `NSArray`

so

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.connectionData)
    {
        NSError *error;
        self.dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        self.matchesArray = self.dict[@"matches"];

        NSArray *title = [self.matchesArray valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"NSString TITLE contains: %@", title);
        self.titleLabel.text = [title lastObject];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.connectionData)
    {
        NSError *error;
        self.dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        self.matchesArray = self.dict[@"matches"];

        NSString *title = [self.matchesArray valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"NSString TITLE contains: %@", title);
        self.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[title objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the values you stored in self.matchesArray  is not a string